# Android Studio problems with latest update

Tags: android, android-studio

I have and Android program which was working up to the last upgrade.
Of course there might have always been a problem which I didn't recognize.
I have attached 2 images, one from HelloIOIO which works,
and one from my program which used to work.

The crux of the problem is:
public class MainActivity extends IOIOActivity {
where it no longer knows what IOIOActivity is.

It has to import the code, which I can see in hello ioio as
Gradle:com.github.ytai.ioio:IOIOLib....
and these imports I don't see in my Project image.

I see what looks like a crucial point in that on hello ioio
src -> main -> java is on the "root"

whereas my program has
app -> src -> main

What do I need to change to get rid of the  "app" folder? It may be this app folder which is causing the software not to see the crucial imports.

Also my .gradle folder has a lot of old versions which I'd like to get rid of. This too may be confusing the issue.

Thanks, Ilan

[image: hello ioio]

[image: my program]

Comment: wow you got yourself in a pickle ;O) app -> src -> main is  the standard module path. You need at least one module to have anything useful. current latest versions are `IDE 3.1.1` ,  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'` (gradle version 4.4). Show your build.gradle files (top level AND module level), then we will see if we can tidy your project up.

Comment: After 3 days of tearing my hair out, I decided it would be easier to start a new project and copy-paste what I need. I must have done something which isn't compatible with the latest version. Starting from scratch seems the only sane way to go.

Comment: Yes after I logged off I had the same thought.

Comment: Finished building the new project - and it works. Thanks for your kind offer to help. I thought I had tried everything, but starting the project from scratch didn't occur to me. The new project has zero errors and zero warnings.